# sed command over multiple lines not working

Tags: sed

I am using sed to replace 14 different abbreviations like CA_23456, CB_scaffold34532,... with 'proper' names in a file and it works putting it all on one line.

```
acc=$1

sed -e 's/CA_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Hesperocyparis_arizonica/;s/CB_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Hesperocyparis_bakeri/;s/CM_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Hesperocyparis_macrocarpa/;s/CS_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Cupressus_sempervirens/;s/CT_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Cupressus_torulosa/;s/JD_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Juniperus_drupacea/;s/JF_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Juniperus_flaccida/;s/JI_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Juniperus_indica/;s/JP_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Juniperus_phoenicea/;s/JX_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Juniperus_procera/;s/JS_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Juniperus_scopulorum/;s/MD_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Microbiota_decussata/;s/XN_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Xanthocyparis_nootkatensis/;s/XV_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Xanthocyparis_vietnamensis/'  ${acc}.nex > ${acc}_replaced.nex
```

To make it more readable I'd like to have the command split over multiple lines using '\' (not all the replacements are shown for brevity)

```
acc=$1

sed -e 's/CA_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Hesperocyparis_arizonica/;\
s/CB_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Hesperocyparis_bakeri/;\
s/CM_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Hesperocyparis_macrocarpa/'\
${acc}.nex > ${acc}_replaced.nex
```

However, I get an error message: sed: -e expression #1, char 168: unterminated address regex. I have looked at the answers to similar problems on various webforums and tried various things (using 's/.../.../' on every line, leaving ';' out,....) but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `\` that escapes the newlines. (They are not actually doing it!, they are interpreted as wrong syntax by sed). However I would suggest to put it into a file and run it like this:

```
sed -f script.sed input
```

where `script.sed` looks like this:

```
s/CA_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Hesperocyparis_arizonica/
s/CB_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Hesperocyparis_bakeri/
s/CM_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Hesperocyparis_macrocarpa/
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the backslashes from the sed code.

Inside singly-quoted shell strings, backslashes are not needed to escape newlines and are not removed because they are not parsed as escape characters. This has the effect that sed sees them as part of its code, and it then expects to find an address regex with a different delimiter than `/` before the command ends at the next newline (similar to `\,/home/, !d`). This address regex does not appear (nor an associated command), and so sed complains about invalid code.

Apart from that: The semicolons in the sed code are no longer necessary when you terminate commands with newlines, and anything involving shell variables should be quoted to avoid splitting in case of whitespace.

In sum:

```
sed -e 's/CA_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Hesperocyparis_arizonica/
        s/CB_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Hesperocyparis_bakeri/
        s/CM_[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/Hesperocyparis_macrocarpa/' \
  "${acc}.nex" > "${acc}_replaced.nex"
```

Comment: I removed the backslashes but now the terminal freezes

Comment: Guessing: Only those in the singly-quoted string should be removed. Also, you have to put a space between the string and the file name `${acc}.nex` (you may want to put double-quotes around that, by the way), or the file name will be considered part of the sed code. I edited in a form of the command that should work.